# Java stream while loop anomaly warnings from PMD

Tags: java, java-stream, static-analysis, pmd

In the following code I create a new ID, check if it exists and return it if it's unique:

```
private String generateNewId(List<Item> items) {
    do {
        String newId = ... // generateNewId from another method
        if (items.stream.noneMatch(i -> i.getId().equals(newId))) {
            return newId;
        }
    } while(true);
}
```

However, I'm getting PMD anomalies:

- Found 'DD'-anomaly for variable 'newId'
- Found 'DU'-anomaly for variable 'newId'

From PMD documentation:

> 1. DU - Anomaly: A recently defined variable is undefined. These
>      anomalies may appear in normal source text.
> 2. DD - Anomaly: A recently
>      defined variable is redefined. This is ominous but don’t have to be a
>      bug.

I tried moving `newId` variable outside the loop but then I got the error: *Variables used in lambda should be final or effectively final*.

How can I refactor my code to get rid of these anomalies? Or should I suppress these warnings as false positives?

Comment: unrelated to the question, but you should't generate IDs like this. The more items you have, the longer this will take (generating n IDs will take O(n^2) steps). You should use UUID, which doesn't technically avoid ID clashes, but they are so improbable that it doesn't matter.

Comment: @Clashsoft I know, unfortunately it's one of the requirements from the client - to maintain backwards compatibility. I'd prefer to use UUID, I just can't...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are seeing the DD anomaly because the variable `newId` is redefined in the `do { } while(true)` loop when the if condition evaluates to false.

The DU anomaly, however, is a false positive, I think. In this case `newId` is always used at least once:

- if the list of items is empty, then `newId` is returned
- if the list of items is not empty, then `newId` is used in the closure of `nonMatch`

But this is something PMD cannot figure out because it does not know the semantics of `noneMatch`. If you would replace `noneMatch` with `anyMatch`, then this would be a true DU anomaly.

DD and DU anomalies are often hard to fix because they point out design issues on a higher level. In this case the problem is not directly the variable `newId` itself but the use of `do { } while(true)` which could result in an infinte loop because you ignore the case where you cannot generate a new unique id.

One way to fix the issue is that you address this problem:

```java
    private String generateNewId(List<Item> items) {
        return Stream.generate(this::getRandomId)
                     .limit(100)
                     .filter(id -> isNew(id, items))
                     .findAny()
                     .orElseThrow(() -> new NoSuchElementException("Failed to generate unique id."));
    }

    private String getRandomId() {
        return "4";  // chosen by fair dice roll.
                     // guaranteed to be random.
    }

    private boolean isNew(String id, List<Item> items) {
        return items.stream().noneMatch(item -> id.equals(item.getId()));
    }
```

This solution addresses the infinite loop problem by trying to generate a new id at most 100 times and throws an exception if it fails. Depending on your situation you might choose a different limit.